# Медиана ряда чисел

Tags: c++

Допустим мы определяем медиану последовательности как число , относительно которого ровно половина элементов меньше , а вторая больше.
Найти медиану получилось , но нашёл я ещё с помощью size().
Нужно найти медиану чётного ряда , что я и сделал , но повторюсь с помощью size() , что не даёт мне использовать их значение.
Например: в чётном отсортированном ряду { 3 , 6 , 7 , 10 }
медианой будет { 6 , 7 } следовательно 6 + 7 / 2 (как это посчитать если я использую номера ряда)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector <double> items;
    double temps(0);
    double sum(0);
    double sum_line(0);

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    cout << " Наберите ряд чисел: для получения Медианы."
        << endl;

    while (cin >> temps)
        items.push_back(temps);
    cout << " Количество элементов в векторе:"
        << items.size() << endl;

    sort(items.begin(), items.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "[V" << i << "] = " << items[i]
             << endl;
    }
    if (items.size() % 2)

        cout << " Медиана не чётного ряда = "
        << items[items.size() - 1] / 2 + 1
        << endl;

    else
        sum += items.size() / 2;
            sum_line += items.size() / 2 + 1;

            cout << sum << endl << sum_line << endl
             << " Среднее значение этих элементов "
             << (sum + sum_line) / 2 << endl; // тут хотел посчитать
                                                      // вычислить их среднее
                                                          // значение. 
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Пожалуйста, используйте Человеческий язык при описании проблемы.

Comment: Нужно написать программу для нахождения медианы из ряда случайных чисел набранных пользователем.

Comment: А что такое sum и sum_line? Они каким боком связаны с медианой?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что в вашем понимании "медиана"?
В мире мат. статистики медианой принято называть такое число X из набора, что половина чисел набора больше X, а половина меньше.
Таким образом медиана при нечетном количестве чисел у вас неверно посчитана, учитывая что массив у вас уже отсортирован:

```
cout << " Медиана не чётного ряда = "
    << items[items.size() - 1] / 2 + 1
    << endl;
```

верно так:

```
cout << " Медиана не чётного ряда = "
    << items[items.size() / 2] // при нечетном количестве это будет середина массива
    << endl;
```

при чётном количестве элементов вы можете выбрать медианой число, лежащее между двумя средними элементами набора:

```
(items[items.size() / 2] + items[items.size() / 2 - 1]) / 2
```

стоит так же учесть крайние случаи (их можно например отдельно обработать): `items.size() == 0 и items.size() == 1`

Comment: `items.size() == 1` можно не обрабатывать отдельно, если доработать одно выражение: `(items.size() - 1) / 2`.

Comment: само собой, но в данном случае не имеет значения где лепить костыль. мне показалось что так нагляднее будет.

Comment: спасибо Вы мне очень помогли.
Я пытался использовать формулу для вычисления медианы.
cout << " Медиана не чётного ряда = "
    << items[items.size() - 1] / 2 + 1
    << endl;

Comment: @iksuy в целом да. Но такой приём позволяет даже выкинуть условие "если размер чётный" :) Ну да неважно, моё дело предложить.

Comment: @its_space, видимо вы что-то не так применили:
имея набор `{ 3, 6, 7, 10, 20 }` медианой данного набора будет число 7.
по вашей формуле это будет число 11

Comment: Интересно, (я правда не в курсе) а если нужно в качестве медианы взять число именно из набора (т.е. *"правильная медиана"* -- вычисленное среднее не годится), то как правильно поступить? Взять то, которое минимально отличается от правильной? А если оба кандидата равноудалены от истины, то левый или правый?

Comment: @avp, думаю что это определяется конкретной задачей.

Comment: @avp в этом случае медианой будет являться [не одно значение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#.D0.9D.D0.B5.D1.83.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C_.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F).

Comment: @avp, если вы решали задачи "правильная медиана" , то я не прочь получить этот опыт от Вас)
Там учитывается "Мода" " шаг" и т д если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @D-side, ну, из этой ссылки я вынес, что все же одно, только какое именно зависит от задачи (договоренности и т.п.). /  Iksuy, ага, понял, общепризнанной методики нет.

Comment: @avp **медианой, по определению, может служить любое число между ними**. Но это по определению. Поскольку для любого из них свойства медианы будут выполняться, можно брать любое. Понятия "нижней/верхней медианы" имеют своё, другое определение :)

Comment: @its_space,  нет, не решал. Слышал когда-то о них, даже употреблял эти слова в разных разговорах, а вот серьезных задач с ними не решал. Поэтому и поинтересовался.

Comment: @D-side, в принципе я все это понял, но это уже "академизм" какой-то, для диссертов и т.п. требуется. Я же на всякий случай для практики поинтересовался.